# opacity 0.5 except this dd

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js, coffeescript, opacity

I want to change body opacity to 0.5 except a focused area selected 'dd'.
In backbone with coffeescript;

I tried and searched for examples;
body changing but not 'dd'.

my code is:

```
@$el is selected dd

...

showhide:->
    $('body').css({opacity:0.5});
    @$el.css({opacity:1});

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do won't work. If we have a look at the [opacity specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) we'll see why not:

> **3.2. Transparency: the ‘opacity’ property**
>
> Opacity can be thought of as a postprocessing operation. Conceptually, after the element (including its descendants) is rendered into an RGBA offscreen image, the opacity setting specifies how to blend the offscreen rendering into the current composite rendering.
>   [...]
>   If the object is a container element, then the effect is as if the contents of the container element were blended against the current background using a mask where the value of each pixel of the mask is `<alphavalue>`.

So if you set the opacity of `<body>` to 0.5, then the browser will render all of `<body>` (including its children and so including your `@$el`) and then composite it onto the browser window with an alpha channel value of 0.5. The result is that the whole page will be rendered at half transparency. Altering the opacity of something inside `<body>` won't matter as the child's opacity will be applied while the child is being rendered into `<body>` and then `<body>`'s opacity will be applied after that.

Consider this pure HTML/CSS example:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
#outer {
    /* ... */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#inner {
    /* ... */
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

The whole thing will come out looking half transparent because the `#inner` opacity is effectively "the opacity with respect to its parent" not "the opacity with respect to the browser window".

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WtAvx/

You're going to have to change your approach. For example, you could position an `opacity: 0.5` element between your `@$el` and `<body>` with a structure like this:

```
<div id="outer"></div>
<div id="inner"></div>
```

and:

```
#outer {
    /* ... */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#inner {
    /* ... */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    opacity: 1.0; /* You don't really need this */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Jsd7q/

You'll probably have to play with the [stacking order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) and insert an absolutely positioned `<div>` with `opacity: 0.5` between your element and `<body>` but I can't say any more give the scant details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

why not use

```
body
{
   background-color:rgba(val,val,val,0.5);//val:0-255
}
```

and set opacity of selected dd as you desire.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
$('body *').not('textarea:focus').css({opacity:'0.5'});
```

Comment: And whit the quotes ?